# cython compiled celely run fail whith [AttributeError: 'method-wrapper' object has no attribute '__module__']

Tags: python, celery, task, cython

I develop a project with the celery in python,and use the cython to compile the pyd files, every files is good but tasks.pyd, it fails to run. I think perhaps the bug is relate to the @decarator,and I try sererval methons with no solution, who can help me? thanks first.

here is my code in tasks.py

```
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger
logger = get_task_logger(__name__)

@app.task
def myTaskFunc(arg1=None, arg2=None):
    some code


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\en-18\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\en-18\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\en-18\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\celery.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\en-18\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\celery\__main__.py", line 16, in main
    _main()
  File "c:\users\en-18\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\celery.py", line 322, in main
    cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
  File "c:\users\en-18\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\celery.py", line 495, in execute_from_commandline
    super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
  File "c:\users\en-18\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\base.py", line 305, in execute_from_commandline
    return self.handle_argv(self.prog_name, argv[1:])
  File "c:\users\en-18\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\celery.py", line 487, in handle_argv
    return self.execute(command, argv)
  File "c:\users\en-18\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\celery.py", line 419, in execute
    ).run_from_argv(self.prog_name, argv[1:], command=argv[0])
  File "c:\users\en-18\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\worker.py", line 223, in run_from_argv
    return self(*args, **options)
  File "c:\users\en-18\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\base.py", line 253, in __call__
    ret = self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\en-18\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\worker.py", line 258, in run
    **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\en-18\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\celery\worker\worker.py", line 97, in __init__
    self.on_before_init(**kwargs)
  File "c:\users\en-18\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\celery\apps\worker.py", line 93, in on_before_init
    trace.setup_worker_optimizations(self.app, self.hostname)
  File "c:\users\en-18\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\celery\app\trace.py", line 596, in setup_worker_optimizations
    app.finalize()
  File "c:\users\en-18\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\celery\app\base.py", line 538, in finalize
    _announce_app_finalized(self)
  File "c:\users\en-18\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\celery\_state.py", line 54, in _announce_app_finalized
    callback(app)
  File "c:\users\en-18\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\celery\app\base.py", line 411, in cons
    return app._task_from_fun(fun, **opts)
  File "c:\users\en-18\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\celery\app\base.py", line 452, in _task_from_fun
    '__header__': staticmethod(head_from_fun(fun, bound=bind)),
  File "c:\users\en-18\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\celery\utils\functional.py", line 279, in head_from_fun
    namespace = {'__name__': fun.__module__}
AttributeError: 'method-wrapper' object has no attribute '__module__'
comtypes        > Calling CoUnititialize()
comtypes        > CoUnititialize() done.
```

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to know without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so what follows is a guess.

I suspect `@app.task` requires the function to have some introspectable attribute that Cython doesn't provide by default. Things to try:

1. Use the directive `#cython: binding=True`. This makes Cython functions a custom object type that behave more like a regular function.
2. Use Cython 3 alpha (although who knows what version of Cython you're using here, since you don't say). It contains some improvements to function introspection (and enables `binding=True` by default).
3. Write this bit of code in Python (you could use `exec` for this for example).

Comment: Thanks DavidW, it has been solved followed by your answer. I don`t know where to set [binding=True] as a cython newer, find no result in it`s manual. so I updated version from 0.29.25 to 3.0.0.a9, and the fail disappeared.

Comment: sorry for have never reading minimal reproducible example in help center, in fact I have never browse the help center. I will read it seriouslly. thanks to DavidW again

Comment: The relevant manual section: https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#compiler-directives - glad it helped

Comment: I gotted it! thanks a lot DavidW